# Code is working when reading data from file but not API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, internationalization, i18next

I was reading value for `translation` from file stored in public folder of react application. file were stored in
[image]

but since our `data` can be changed anytime so we are storing data into database. at loadtime after detecting the language from browser data of that langauge will be called from `API` and will be used directly. so below file code is working perfectly.

```
import i18next from 'i18next';

const LanguageDetector =  require("i18next-browser-languagedetector");
const initReactI18next = require("react-i18next");

import { TRANSLATIONS_EN } from "../public/locales/en/en.js";
import { TRANSLATIONS_IT } from "../public/locales/it/it.js";


i18next
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
 .init({
  
   resources: {   
     en:TRANSLATIONS_EN,   
     it:TRANSLATIONS_IT,
   },
   fallbackLng: 'fr'
 }); 

 
i18next.changeLanguage(navigator.language);

export default i18next;
```

now instead of this I am using below code in which I am calling `API` to read the `data` and it will be assigned directly to `variable`. we wont write data to file
in below code instead of static `files` I have called API. if I print output of API or file they are exactly same. but not able to understand why this is not working. can `asynchronous` be the reason?

```
  import i18next from 'i18next';
    import React from 'react';
    import TransFile from './TransFile.js';
    import apiDelegate from '../src/components/Utils/Common/api.js';
    
    const LanguageDetector = require('i18next-browser-languagedetector');
    const initReactI18next = require('react-i18next');
    

    import { TRANSLATIONS_EN } from '../public/locales/en/en.js'; //just for verification

    import makeGetRequest from './abc.js';
    apiDelegate.getTranslations().then((result) => {
     output = JSON.stringify(result);
     const tr_en = 'translation: ' +JSON.parse(output) ;
      alert(tr_en);  //this and below alert produce same result.
      alert(TRANSLATIONS_EN));
    
      i18next
        .use(LanguageDetector)
        .use(initReactI18next)
        .init({
          resources: {
            en: tr_en,   //if I write TRANSLATIONS_EN here it works
       },
          fallbackLng: 'fr',
        });
    
    
      i18next.changeLanguage(navigator.language);
    });
    export default i18next;
```

not able to understand strange issue. is there any better way to handle? I found `i18n-http-backend` api but from this I dont know how to call `restAPI`. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to incorporate API data in i18next instead of static file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70589040/how-to-incorporate-api-data-in-i18next-instead-of-static-file)

Answer (score 1):

The first `then` is handling the response header... You need a second `then` to process the response body. Try:

```
apiDelegate.getTranslations()
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    // ... Your code
  })
```

Comment: it is not working.